# Identify duplicate value and increment by one there onwards in sql

Tags: t-sql

I have to write a sql script, to identify a duplicate values, once I identify the duplicate, I have to increment the value by one there onwards in subsequent rows.

Here's my data:

```
Id      ParentId    Status  SortOrder 
15436   8918        1       0 
10288   8918        1       1 
13162   8918        1       2 
18447   8918        1       2 
19257   8918        1       3 
26911   8918        1       4 
25578   8918        1       5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. If not, it would help if you added your desired results in your question. Try this out:

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE(Id INT,ParentId INT, [Status] INT,SortOrder INT);

INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES  (15436,8918,1,0),
        (10288,8918,1,1),
        (13162,8918,1,2),
        (18447,8918,1,2),
        (19257,8918,1,3),
        (26911,8918,1,4),
        (25578,8918,1,5);


SELECT  ID,
        ParentID,
        [Status],
        SortOrder,
        [NewSortOrder] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentID ORDER BY sortOrder,ID) - 1
FROM @yourTable
```

Results:

```
ID          ParentID    Status      SortOrder   NewSortOrder
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
15436       8918        1           0           0
10288       8918        1           1           1
13162       8918        1           2           2
18447       8918        1           2           3
19257       8918        1           3           4
26911       8918        1           4           5
25578       8918        1           5           6
```

Comment: Id ParentId Status SortOrder
15436 8918 1 0
10288 8918 1 1
13162 8918 1 2
18447 8918 1 2
19257 8918 1 3
26911 8918 1 4
25578 8918 1 5

Comment: I see you are new to stackoverflow. It's recommended to keep the information about the question in the question area not the comment section. I edited your answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, but that is not the output you want, may be I was not clear.. I don't want to see the duplicate sort order under same parent id, If you see above there are two '2's. I want a script where, if you see duplicate sort order, increment by 1 there onwards, the output sort order should be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,....

Comment: Oh so you want a new sort order. See my edited code.